# how to assign "container registry" permissions to virtual machine in Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-container-registry, google-container-os

I'm creating a virtual machine in [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com) with full access scopes
[image]

When I connect to the virtual machine by SSH and try to pull a docker image from [Container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/), it throws permissions error:

[image]

So I wonder how do I give permissions for my [Container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/)

I thought giving full access to API would solve this problem, but it doesn't

By the way I know I can directly put image from container registry to compute engine, but this is not what I want, it's not gonna be only one image I'll be running, it's gonna be some of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions for Container Registry are controlled by Cloud Storage IAM. Container Registry stores container images in a Cloud Storage bucket in your project.

To authorize `docker` to use Google credentials there are several methods. I use this method:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

However, that method is no longer recommended. This method is recommended:

```
gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr
docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

[Container Registry Authentication Methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)

Comment: thanks, but how do I install gcloud inside the virtual machine? because container-optimize os(the os I'm using in the virtual machine) does not have gcloud installed

Comment: Check this answer and create a new question.